# Making a copy/clone of a "List<List<Map>>"

Tags: flutter, reference, copy, clone

I'm trying to create a copy/clone of a "List<List<Map'>>".

So far I tried:

```
dataFTY2 = dataFTY.map((element)=>element).toList();
dataFTY2 = json.decode(json.encode(dataFTY));
dataFTY2 = List.from(dataFTY);
```

Nothing seems to work. Whenever I change the copy "dataFTY2", dataFTY changes as well. I need this to be a completely independent copy. Please help. I cant seem to figure this out, its driving me crazy.

More code added for reference.

```
List failureDetails = [];
    List trackIDs = [];
    List dateTime = [];
    var dataFTY2 = dataFTY.map((element) => element.map((ele) => Map.from(ele)).toList()).toList();

    // get historyData for each one and sort through "F"s and put them into the table in a row?
    for (var x in dataFTY2[4]) {
      trackIDs.add(x["track_id"]);
      dateTime.add(x["datetime"]);
    }
    List failuresOnly = List.filled(trackIDs.length, {}, growable: true);
    for (var i = 0; i < trackIDs.length; i++) {
      await fetchTrackIDTestDetails(context, trackIDs[i], dateTime[i], false);
      failureDetails.add(MyGlobals().getTestCodeDetailsData());
    }
    //filter out only "F"s
    for (var p = 0; p < failureDetails.length; p++) {
      for (var t in failureDetails[p][0]) {
        if (t["Status"] == "F") {
          //add it to list, if pass do nothing
          failuresOnly[p] = t;
        }
      }
    }
    //combine with FTY failure data, don't use new screen use old screen and toggle when pressed, add column on right side
    //dataFTY2 = MyGlobals().getFTYFailureMoreDetails();
    for (var i = 0; i < dataFTY2[4].length; i++) {
      dataFTY2[4][i]["TestCode"] = failuresOnly[i]["TestCode"];
      dataFTY2[4][i]["Status"] = failuresOnly[i]["Status"];
      dataFTY2[4][i]["TestValue"] = failuresOnly[i]["TestValue"];
      dataFTY2[4][i]["Lo_Limit"] = failuresOnly[i]["Lo_Limit"];
      dataFTY2[4][i]["Up_Limit"] = failuresOnly[i]["Up_Limit"];
      dataFTY2[4][i]["ProcTime"] = failuresOnly[i]["ProcTime"];
    }
```

Comment: `List<List<Map>> list1 = const [[{"1":"first"}]];
  List<List<Map>> list2 = List.from(list1);
  list2.add([{"2":"second"}]);
  print(list1);
  print(list2);`

I don't see any dart related bug.

Comment: Maybe this will help, but my List<List<Map>> contains other variables like List<Map> failureLinksMap = [{}]; Not sure if that would matter of not when making the copy. But none of the solutions have worked so far. I even tried putting List.from() on all of the variables that are inside of the main List<List<Map>> and its still not working.

Comment: Not sure what i changed to be honest but I got it to work. There must have been something else in my code that was causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Map.from](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.0/dart-core/Map/Map.from.html) named constructor to clone the `Map` like this,

```
dataFTY2 = dataFTY.map((element) => element.map((ele) => Map.from(ele)).toList()).toList();
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt seem too work. When i make a change to the copy the orginal still changes...

Comment: Not sure what i changed to be honest but I got it to work. There must have been something else in my code that was causing an issue. I ended up using this method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I find it more straightforward to use collection-`for` and the spread (`...`) operator:

```dart
void main() {
  var original = [
    [
      {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2},
      {'foo': 3, 'bar': 4},
    ]
  ];

  // Create a new List...
  var copy = [
    for (var sublist in original)
      // ... where each element is a new List...
      [
        for (var map in sublist)
          // ... where each element of the sublist is a new Map that
          // copies all entries from `map`.
          {...map},
      ],
  ];

  original[0][0]['foo'] = -1;
  print(original); // Prints: [[{foo: -1, bar: 2}, {foo: 3, bar: 4}]]
  print(copy); // Prints: [[{foo: 1, bar: 2}, {foo: 3, bar: 4}]]
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt seem too work. When i make a change to the copy the orginal still changes...

Comment: Maybe this will help, but my List<List<Map>> contains other variables like List<Map> failureLinksMap = [{}]; Not sure if that would matter of not when making the copy. But none of the solutions have worked so far. I even tried putting List.from() on all of the variables that are inside of the main List<List<Map>> and its still not working.